# Can I hand a C++ object to protobuf

Tags: c++, type-conversion, protocol-buffers

I just started using Protobuf and have some troubles.
I have the following message definitions:

```
message bottom1{
    int ...
}

message bottom2{
    int ...
}

message bottom3{
    int ...
}

message bottom4{
    int ...
}

message mid1{
    bottom1 ...
    bottom2 ...
}

message mid2{
    bottom3 ...
    bottom4 ...
}

message top{
    mid1 ...
    mid2 ...
}
```

Now my c++ program is already built exactly like that. I now want to store a top c++ object. Is it possible to just hand over the c++ object to protobuf or at least only hand over top.mid1 and top.mid2 to protobuf. Or do I need to build the message myself from bottom to the top?

Comment: No, you can't _"just hand it over"_, protobuf needs to know an appropriate message structure to represent that object in it's own protocol language. You have to define that, and write mapping code to set the message fields from you object data and vice versa.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for the answer. Its my first post so I don't know how to upvote your comment. But thank you nonetheless.